# HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've hosted a site in IIS but whenever I browse to the site I get 404.4. How can I solve this? I've referred several posts and they all say the issue is about staticfile but it is already mapped. What more can I do? Here is the attached picture of handler mappings in my iis 7.0

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I have this url rewriter set up:

```
<rules>


       <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="80" />


          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://abc.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

When I disable this rule the http:// request is correctly handled. But when I enable it, I get this error.

Yet another update:

If I replace this:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://abc.com/{R:1}" />
```

with

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://abc.com/{R:1}" />
```

It all works out pretty well.

Comment: On Azure, the following blog may also help: https://ppolyzos.com/2015/10/26/reverse-proxy-functionality-in-azure-web-sites/

Answer (score 18):

I was having the exact same issue. I installed Application Request Routing component and then set the Proxy enabled and selected the Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests entered the redirect url alias and mine worked

Comment: And this is how you enable the proxy after installing ARR https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/iis-docs/blob/master/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing.md#user-content-configure-arr-as-a-forward-proxy

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you... this has been causing me issues all day!