# IIS RewriteUrl RegularExpression

Tags: regex, iis, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I'm using IIS 7.5 and UrlRewrite Module 2.  I've read the official documentation for the module [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module), as well as many examples on SO and tested my regex on [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/).  Somehow the translation into the Web.config file is causing me problems.  I've tried escaping the parantheses also.

The regex I'm using is:

```
^partners/(var|distributors|msp|techpartners)/(na|emea|apac)(|/)(.*)
```

a few example urls:

```
partners/var/emea

partners/msp/apac/

partners/var/na/abcdabcdabcd
```

Here is the web.config I have so far:

```xml
<rules>
  <rule name="partnersListing" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^partners/(var|distributors|msp|techpartners)/(na|emea|apac)(|/)(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="partnersList.aspx?type=${R:1}&region={R:2}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Not sure if I want the action to be Rewrite or Redirect yet, but the pattern isn't working either way.  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this rule in the site root `web.config` or a subdirectory `web.config`?

Comment: @Kev in a subdirectory: "/partners"

Comment: I also needed to install [ApplicationRequestRouting](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7895377/1163940

Comment: How odd, you usually only need that if you're reverse proxying or require outbound url rewriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your answer to my question in the comments:

> Is this rule in the site root web.config or a subdirectory web.config?
>
> @Kev in a subdirectory: "/partners"

From the docs:

> http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference?amp;clcid=0x409

Quote:

> Note that the input URL string passed to a distributed rule is always
>   relative to the location of the Web.config file where the rule is
>   defined. For example, if a request is made for
>   http://www.mysite.com/content/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=3, and a
>   rewrite rule is defined in the /content directory, then the rule gets
>   this URL string default.aspx as an input.

Based on this you need to change your url match to:

```
^(var|distributors|msp|techpartners)/(na|emea|apac)(|/)(.*)
```

Assuming your re-write rule exists in:

```
http://example.com/partners/web.config
```

There is just one other thing which is what appears to be an extraneous `$` character in your redirect/rewrite url in front of back reference `{R:1}`, I'm not sure if you intended that to be there or not.

Comment: Fantastic! The note about where to put the rule and where the input location is read from helped! Thank you very much!!