# Http message with with absolute URL instead of absolute path gives 404 error using IIS

Tags: http, iis

When sending a message using the HttpClient from C# it will send the following to the server:

```
Delete http://test.com/v1/client HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com
Content-Length: 0
```

And this results in a 404 message from the IIS server:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2019 09:56:06 GMT
Content-Length: 5100

...
```

But sending the following message with a absolute path instead of an absolute URL:

```
Delete /v1/client HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com
Content-Length: 0
```

Gives back a 200 message like expected.

What do I need to change on my IIS server so that it would also accept HTTP messages using a absolute URL?

The [specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5) says that both are allowed so there is no issue with the HttpClient.

#### IIS logs

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2019-08-22 08:17:09
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2019-08-22 08:17:09 127.0.0.1 Delete /v1/client/webhook - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - - 404 4 2 3
```

It looks like an [404.4 - No handler configured](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0) error.

Comment: Read IIS log files to see what kind of 404 you hit, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: please check that your entered domain name is right and also check the iis bindings.

Comment: @LexLi

#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2019-08-22 08:17:29 127.0.0.1 Delete /v1/client- 80 - 127.0.0.1 - - 404 4 2 3

Comment: I have updated the original question with the IIS logs and the 404.4 No handler configured error.

Comment: I have tried following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895377/3576578 but it doesn't work, It gives me bad gateway errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue IIS can't handle "Get" method with lowercasing. If I send "GET" everything works fine.